# Finding the number of elements in a circular queue

Tags: c++, arrays, modulus

Say I have an circular queue implemented using an array of size 10. Without using the `sizeof` function in C++, how would one go about finding the number of elements in the array or in other words the number of indexes that have been used.  I figure using modular math since I know the first and final indexes but how exactly would one right this into a function that return this size?

Comment: By not living in the '80s and by using `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find the size of a C-style array other than using `sizeof`; that's one reason for the existence of that operator. Modulus sure won't help you.

Now, for C++'s `std::array` template class, you can simply use the `size()` method.

EDIT: if you already now the last "possible" index (the first is *always* 0), you can just use that plus one as length.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you know the size of the array, but you want to know how many indices in the array are populated with an actual value that is not NULL or the default value. If that is the case, worst case you will have to iterate the array and check each index.

You could always make your life a little easier by doing a little bookkeeping and keeping track of the populated index count yourself. Each time you add a value to the array, increment your count. Decrement the count when you remove. If you update an already populated index leave the count alone.